# Access multiple rasters with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, mosaic, wcs

I am curious if anyone knows if, and how, it would be possible to configure GeoServer to provide download (GetCoverage) capabilities to multiple adjacent rasters.  A GeoServer mosaic comes close, but provides only the single process image rather than the multiple "unaltered" raw originals that were used to build it.

Ideally, I'd like the user to be able treat the dataset as if it were uniform (e.g. DRGs for a state), but be able to access the original QQ that compose the mosaic.  From what I can tell, GeoServer doesn't support this particular kind of interaction, but perhaps there exists a plugin I haven't yet heard of.

Comment: could you serve any one of the multiple rasters from geoserver and then have the front end fetch the different rasters using different layers?

Comment: If you're after creating a single coverage from multiple rasters, you could manage that be loading all the data into rasdaman, then access the data through the GDAL extension I think

Comment: This question has possibly been corrected in a new version of the software and no longer relevant.  It also seems this question is more likely either a non GIS issue (read programming).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is likely to have been fixed in newer versions of the software